# Is there a way to set the load priority of images on a site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Controlling image load order in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211519/controlling-image-load-order-in-html)

Is there a way to set the load priority or the loading sequence of images on a web site?

Comment: You should provide more detail. Are you loading via JavaScript?  (Post is tagged JavaScript) Do you mean via HTML only?

Comment: you could use javascript dynamically to add css clases which has a background property attributes to the elements

Comment: @John Conde - I think that the system used in "Controlling image load order in HTML" is quite uneffective, when a site has hundreds of images on it.

Comment: @Jim Schubert - The images are loaded only as an img or as a background in div and td.

Comment: @david - I'm not sure what you mean exactly, is there an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and try sth. like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var preloaded_image = $('<img />').attr('src', 'img.jpg');

  $('#img_div').append(preloaded_image);
});
```

This should cause the images to load after the rest of the content.