# In what order will Chrome (and others) load <img>'s? How to change this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, preload

I have a very heavy page and I am trying to better engineer the order in which elements are loaded, preload some stuff and strategically leave other things unloaded.

Chrome seems to load the bottom of the page before the top of the page? This seems counter intuitive and I wonder if I am doing anything to cause this. Is this normal behavior? Will Chrome load elements by the order they appear in the CSS or by the order they are called in HTML?

Comment: Related question that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211519/controlling-image-load-order-in-html

Answer (score 0):

It should have limited number of async connections for the external http calls, lets take 4 for example (they are more, something like 50) and you can have:

img_1.jpg
img_2.jpg
..
img_n.jpg

It starts to load the first 4, when one finishes, slots are getting free so it loads img_5.

On your concrete questions - leave the priority ones in the HTML and load the heavy ones by using JS I guess (you can follow the topic J L gave you above)