# Can't callback a function after .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this according to: [Controlling image load order in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211548/3809152)

I replaced the 'src' changing with '.attr' function, and it can't callback anymore. It stopped after changing once:

This line:`I.src = imgAddresses[counter];`

Into this:`$("#page"+counter).attr("data-bgimage",imgAddresses[counter]);`

Can you help me? Thank you very much!

HTML:

```
    <div id="intro" class="slidingSpaces demo0" data-bgimage='' title="Intro">
        <p>Hello</p>
    <div id="page0" class="slidingSpaces demo0" data-bgimage='' title="Cover">
        </div>
    <div id="page1" class="slidingSpaces demo0" data-bgimage='' title="01">
        </div>
    <div id="page2" class="slidingSpaces demo0" data-bgimage='' title="02">
        </div>
```

JS:

```
var imgAddresses = ['img1.png','img2.png','img3.png'];

function loadImage(counter) {
  //Break out if no more images
  if(counter==imgAddresses.length) { return; }

  //Grab an image obj
  var I = document.getElementById("page"+counter);

  //Monitor load or error events, moving on to next image in either case
  I.onload = I.onerror = function() { loadImage(counter+1); },

  //Change source (then wait for event)
  $("#page"+counter).attr("data-bgimage",imgAddresses[counter]);

}

loadImage(0);
```

Notice: "data-bgimage" is from [FerroSlider jQuery Plugin.](http://www.alessandroferrini.it/lab/jQueryPlugins/ferroSlider/docs/docs.php)
The div **must** use that for background-image.

Comment: it should be `$("#page"+counter).attr("src",imgAddresses[counter]);`

Comment: Where is a callback expected?

Comment: @Think Different: Sorry, the div use "data-bgimage" for background image, so I can't use the "src"...

Comment: @gotomanners: It should work on when the "counter+1", but I don't know why it stop.

Comment: Are you basically trying to load images into a page, and then use the FerroSlider with them?

Comment: @ rwacarter: I'm trying to load the div's background-image in order. Each div is a slide using FerroSlider plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why its not working**

You cannot use `onload` or `onerror` on `<div>` elements.

The onload event can only be used on the the following elements
`<body>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>`, `<style>` ... basically elements containing external resources.

The `<div>`is not an external resource as it's loaded as part of the body, so the onload event doesn't apply there.

**Some possible solutions**

Without understanding your full requirements and limitiations, I can see that you could

1. Use `<img>` tags
2. Call your `loadImage()` function in a loop.

   ```
   for(var i=0; i < imgAddresses.length; i++) {
       loadImage(i);
   }
   ```
3. This may be overkill but you can use [DOM Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers) which will notify you every time the dom change

   ```
   var imgAddresses = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'];
   var observers = [];

   function loadImage(counter) {
       //Break out and clean up if no more images
       if (counter === imgAddresses.length) {
           observers.forEach(function (observer) {
               // later, you can stop observing
               observer.disconnect();
           });
           //delete observers array
           observers.splice(0, counter);
           return;
       }

       var target = document.querySelector("#page" + counter);

       // create an observer instance
       var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
           mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
               console.log("page " + counter + " changed", mutation.target);
               loadImage(counter + 1);
           });
       });
       observers.push(observer);

       // configuration of the observer:
       var config = {
           attributes: true, // monitoring attrs only
           childList: false,
           characterData: false
       };

       // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
       observer.observe(target, config);

       //Change attr (then wait for observer to pick up change)
       $(target).attr("data-bgimage", imgAddresses[counter]);
   }

   loadImage(0);
   ```

   Try it out in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gotomanners/sogzy5yy/

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I don't really know coding so... I'm trying to  load the background-image in order. Is there any other way?

Comment: Thank you gotomanners. I tried all the solution and sorry, can't work. But well, after all the ideas, I've found a work-around way with img tag. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to edit a data-* attribute you should use .data()

```
var imgAddresses = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'];

function loadImage(images) {
    for(var i = 0; i < imgAddresses.length; i++){
        $('#page' + i).data('bgimage', imgAddresses[i]);
    }

}

loadImage(imgAddresses);
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, it's not a data-* attribute :)

Comment: Any attribute starting with "data-" is considered a data attribute, check it out here :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Also just edited the entire code as it looks like the callbacks you are using will not work so instead popped it in a for loop to load all the imgAddresses into the data-bgimage attributes

Comment: Thank you. Somehow, all the images load at the same time. I can't make it load in order like 1st loaded then 2nd load. My images are in HD so I try to make them load sequentially.