# Dynamically loading in order images from the server (for html gallery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I made a wowslider gallery dynamic so it loads all the images from a specific folder. The problem though is that they all get loaded simultaneously and take too long to load. I want them to load in order, one by one using js or jquery. My code;

```
<div class="ws_images"  >
<ul>
    <?php // start looping the pics 
    $inc = 0;
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator('gallery/data1/images/') as $file) {
    if($file->isDot()) continue; 
    $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file->getFilename()); //removing the extension
    ?>

    <li>
    <img class='imgs' src="gallery/data1/images/<?php echo $file->getFilename();  ?>" alt="<?php echo $withoutExt ?>" title="<?php echo $withoutExt;  ?>" id="wows1_<?php echo $inc; $inc++; ?>"/>
    </li>
    <?php } // ending the loop ?>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

I've found this thread [Controlling image load order in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211519/controlling-image-load-order-in-html) which solves the problem i guess but I can't implement it to my dynamic code... I tried many approaches but none of them worked, please help !

Comment: so you want for the second image to wait until first one is loaded ?

Comment: yes exactly but dynamically because we don't know how many images exist on the server on a given time

Comment: did you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have something implementin the code from that answer you posted here

```
<div class="ws_images"  >
    <ul>
        <?php // start looping the pics 
            $inc = 0;
            foreach (new DirectoryIterator('gallery/data1/images/') as $file) {
            if($file->isDot()) continue; 
            $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file->getFilename()); //removing the extension
            ?>

            <li>
            <img class='imgs' img-name="<?php echo $file->getFilename();  ?>" src="" alt="<?php echo $withoutExt ?>" title="<?php echo $withoutExt;  ?>" id="wows1_<?php echo $inc; $inc++; ?>"/>
            </li>
        <?php } // ending the loop ?>

    </ul>
</div>



<script>
    var imgAddresses = [];

    $('.ws_images ul li').each(function(){
        imgAddresses.push($(this).find('img').attr('img-name'));
    });



    function loadImage(counter) {
      //Break out if no more images
      if(counter==imgAddresses.length) { return; }

      //Grab an image obj
      var I = document.getElementById("wows1_"+counter);

      //Monitor load or error events, moving on to next image in either case
      I.onload = I.onerror = function() { loadImage(counter+1); }

      //Change source (then wait for event)
      I.src = 'gallery/data1/images/'+imgAddresses[counter];
    }

    loadImage(0);
</script>
```

You need to test this code because i didn't test it but i wrote it just to give you an idea how to do that

Comment: check it out bro.
http://testing.mkitra.com/5/gallery.php
Works nice but the first image doesn't load