# Preload image queue

Tags: html, css, image, preload

is there a way to change my queue order for images?

I have an image which i use as a "blur" preview for an bigger image. I use a cms so there are a lot of images which load before my image. Even preload is ignored.

The order is:

- Body with background image
- 27 images
- Custom preview image

What I try is to change my queue order

- Body
- custom Preview image
- 27 images

My image is a low resolution image. It is 85x53 and its size is about 2,13kb.
And it start at 1,4s (Sometimes even later).

[image]

Thanks for any help :)

Kind regards,
Rakowu

Comment: Posible clone:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211519/controlling-image-load-order-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a hidden `<img>` tag at the top of your body to force the browser to load it earlier

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
 <img src="your/preloaded/image.png" style="display: none;"/>
 <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes i already tried that, i even put an preload link in the head section :/
(My bad, i should have written what i've already tried).
I should also point out that i'm using smarty to load the image.

Comment: Ok Sorry, you're right, i used background-image instead of the image tag. There still some images loading before, but it loads now fast enough for the desired result, so thank you :)