# fetch priority attribute in <img> tag react js

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

As the lighthouse suggests, I need to set priority to the LCP in my react project. I was trying to use `fetchpriority` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/fetchPriority) attribute on the `<img>` tag and my lint is complaining about that attribute not existing. I am using react 17.0.2 with typescript. don't we have the support for `fetchpriority` attribute from react yet? Anyone know a work around for fix the lighthouse suggestion? [preload-important-resources](https://web.dev/optimize-lcp/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools#preload-important-resources)

Comment: This has enough info on what you are looking for i think
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802121/react-js-marking-importance-priority-of-img-loading

Comment: I saw that thread already, It has a way to do it from js level, I'm looking for a simple attribute in html, which can do the trick. It has a good browser support already, but seems the react does not update it yet

Answer (score 3):

You can define a type declaration that extends React's. Create a file in your project (e.g. `custom.d.ts`) with a definition like this:

```
import { AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes } from "react";

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    fetchpriority?: 'high' | 'low' | 'auto';
  }
};
```

and then reference it from your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "include": [
    "custom.d.ts",
    ...
  ]
}
```

From that moment on you should be able to declare an `img` element with a `fetchpriority` attribute.

Comment: this seems will do the trick, quick hack, but worth a trying.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import React from "react";

declare module "react" {
  interface ImgHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    fetchPriority?: 'high' | 'low' | 'auto';
  }
}
```

p.s. don't forget to import React

Answer (score -1):

Another option, in your `global.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace React {
  interface ImgHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    fetchPriority?: 'high' | 'low' | 'auto';
  }
}
```