# Property 'fetchPriority' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>'

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to add "fetchPriority" to link tag as below.

```
const optionalPreload =
    ServerOnlyHead  ? (
      <ServerOnlyHead
        children={
          <link
            fetchPriority="high" // error here !!!
            rel="preload"
            as="image"
            href={image?.src || ""}
          />
        }
      />
    ) : null;
```

but it throws following error,

[image]

```
Type '{ fetchPriority: string; rel: string; as: string; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>'.
  Property 'fetchPriority' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>'.ts(2322)
'fetchPriority' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
```

i could see that LinkHTMLAttributes do not have "fetchPriority" property.

```
interface LinkHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
        as?: string | undefined;
        crossOrigin?: string | undefined;
        href?: string | undefined;
        hrefLang?: string | undefined;
        integrity?: string | undefined;
        media?: string | undefined;
        imageSrcSet?: string | undefined;
        referrerPolicy?: HTMLAttributeReferrerPolicy | undefined;
        rel?: string | undefined;
        sizes?: string | undefined;
        type?: string | undefined;
        charSet?: string | undefined;
    }
```

could some one please let me know how to resolve this ?

Thanks!!

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455263/fetch-priority-attribute-in-img-tag-react-js/) might be helpful. Check it out.

Comment: TS only implements when supported by two browser engines. Right now only Chrome/Edge support fetch priority.